# Can't clone from bitbucket repository

Tags: amazon-ec2, jenkins

I can't clone git repository from BitBucket by jenkins on amazon ec2.
OS:Centos
Git:2.0.4

Step which done:

1. Add ssh key to bitbucket
2. Add bitbucket to known_host
3. jenkins run from user tomcat

directory listing:

```
drwx------ 2 tomcat tomcat 4096 Nov 14 15:51 .
drwx------ 3 tomcat tomcat 4096 Nov 14 08:40 ..
-rw------- 1 tomcat tomcat 1675 Nov 14 08:41 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat  404 Nov 14 08:41 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat  806 Nov 14 08:55 known_host
```

Here ps -ef | grep jenkins

```
tomcat    1544     1  0 Nov14 ?        00:03:46 /etc/alternatives/java Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=8090 --ajp13Port=8019 --debug=5 --><handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
tomcat    7018  6957  0 17:04 pts/0    00:00:00 grep jenkins
```

In jenkins configuration job I see

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:my-account/my-repo.git HEAD
```

When I run job to build I got error

```
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@bitbucket.org:my-account/my-repo.git
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Build-project # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

When I tried to clone directly from command line everything works fine
Could you please help me to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying your repository credentials correctly? In the Source Code Management section of the job configuration, click the Add button to add a Credentials entry that uses the SSH key you added to your Bitbucket repo. I usually save my private key file on the filesystem where it's readable only by Tomcat, select  the "From a file on Jenkins master" option in the Add Credentials dialog, and specify the path to my private key file. Make sure the Username is `git` (as in `git@bitbucket.org`).

Once you've added the credentials, select that entry from the dropdown list in the job configuration. When the focus leaves that box, an error message will appear if Jenkins is unable to `git ls-remote` from that repo using the credentials you provided.